# change php variable using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change php variable using ajax

```
$("#modals_01 .linkL").click(function(){
var a = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
alert (a); // balls
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/items.php",
    data: {category : a},
    success: function() {
        $("#panelB").load("inc/items.php");
    }
});
});
```

items.php

```
$category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : "lamps";
echo $category;  // lamps
```

How can I get `balls` as `$category` value ?

Comment: do you want default category value as balls instead of lamps or you want to pass lamps as category?

Comment: `success: function( data ) { $("#panelB").html( data ); }`

Comment: I would suggest you check that `balls` is indeed being sent to items.php. If it isn't it will default to `lamps`. You could also use an if/else statement. Or `if(!isset($_POST['category']) $category = 'doh';`

Comment: @RamSharma, default value for category is `lamps`. I need to pass `balls` or anything as its value using jquery ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below and use $_GET instead of $_POST:-

```
$("#panelB").load("inc/items.php", { "category": a})
```

Comment: works perfectly! But, what is then the purpose of ajax code at all, if it is possible to do with this one line of code?

Comment: No need to write ajax code with this. You can check here :- http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

In success function use like this:

```
success: function(response) {      // return content from php page
        $("#panelB").html(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```